# Receive msgInfo from socket.reciveMessageFrom after using select c#

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I use a few virtual Ip's on my computer and then I get a msg I need to know on which Ip I received the message.

I used ReceiveMessageFrom and it worked great till I addded select.
after select the info  recived is not valid

my code :

```
    IPEndPoint ipep2 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any , xxx);
    Socket socket2 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
        SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    socket2.Bind(ipep2);

    ArrayList copySocketsList = new ArrayList();
    copySocketsList.Add(socket2);

    Socket.Select(copySocketsList  , null , null , 1000);

    foreach(Socket soc in copySocketsList)
    {
        int recv = soc.ReceiveMessageFrom(data , 0 , 1024 , ref flags , ref Remote , out ipInfo);

    }
```

in that example the ipInfo is not valid but if we remove the select it will be fine

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at this:
[Socket.ReceiveMessageFrom Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivemessagefrom.aspx)

> However, the returned IPPacketInformation object will only be valid
>   for packets which arrive at the local computer after the socket option
>   has been set. If a socket is sent packets between when it is bound to
>   a local endpoint (explicitly by the Bind method or implicitly by one
>   of the Connect, ConnectAsync, SendTo, or SendToAsync methods) and its
>   first call to the ReceiveMessageFrom method, calls to
>   ReceiveMessageFrom method will return invalid IPPacketInformation
>   objects for these packets.
>
> To ensure that all IPPacketInformation objects are valid, an application should set the PacketInformation socket option to true before it is bound to a local endpoint using the SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel, SocketOptionName, Boolean) method.